# Increasing the time for requests to complete

Tags: configuration, timeout, wordpress

I have a one off web request that I need to send via a Wordpress page hosted on my server.

The request takes a long time because it's processing a lot of data; unfortunately, the page returns with an error page before the request has had time to completed. (There's nothing wrong with the request per se; I know, because when I pass it a smaller set of data, it completes with no problems.)

My question is:

**What settings can I change on the server to increase the length of time that passes before the server kills the request?**

So far I have changed these:

- In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`: `Timeout`.
- In `/etc/php.ini`: `default_socket_timeout` and `mysql.connect_timeout`.
- In `/etc/my.cnf`: `connect_timeout`, `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout`

But none of these changes make a difference.

Comment: How are you testing this connection? Are you using `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: @slm, I'm not sure what you mean by 'testing the connection', but I am making a request that uses a connection to my server. I am making this request via a wordpress page that is hosted on my server.

Comment: Are you using a browser to do this? What is the request? Is it javascript pulling another server, we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini`, adjust `max_execution_time`.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, and I was about to jump for joy at having got a solution... but when I tried it, it didn't work. I'm wondering whether there is some php code that can be used to override whatever is in the php/apache settings.

Comment: Indeed, PHP has a lot of methods to override settings in the INI file.  Look in your code for any instances of `ini_set()` calls.  Also, check your server logs for what may be helpful information when the attempts fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to tweek the script itself using  `set_time_limit()` and extend as *ad libitum*, see doc at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php